# Netezza, how to RAISE NOTICE with current time

Tags: time, timestamp, netezza, notice, raise

Im trying to debug Netezza procedure using RAISE NOTICE after UPDATE AND INSERT queries. Im trying to show the current time after each query is finished. 
I tried something like this:

```
RAISE NOTICE 'UPDATE time=%', now();
```

But that doesn't work. Only way I have had it working is to define a timestamp variable at the beginning of procedure and then just before raising notice I define this variablie like this:

```
timevar:=now();
RAISE NOTICE 'UPDATE time=%', timevar;
```

Is there a way where I can combine it just in one line and not have to define a new variable at beginning of procedure and assining it  now() each time I whant to RAISE NOTICE ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RAISE only accepts identifiers as arguments after the format expression. The way you are currently doing it is really the only way.

```
The statement syntax follows:  
RAISE level ’format’ [, identifier [...]];
```

Answer (score 3):

When you want to track progress through several steps in the same transaction, you can't use `now()` as that won't change.

It's a feature of transaction management within Postgres, that all statements within the same transaction get the same value for `now()`

However `timeofday()` DOES change, so you can use that.

And you can use a function in the place of identifier:

```
RAISE NOTICE 'UPDATE time=%', timeofday();
```